# How to fire parent's event handler from descendant, so that `e.target` is the descendant?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
var parent = document.createElement('div'),
    child = parent.cloneNode(false);
parent.appendChild(child);
parent['on'+event] = function(e){
    // Do something with e.target
};
```

I want to fire `parent['on'+event]` with `e.target` being `child`.

I have tried:

```
parent['on'+event]({target:child});
```

...and it works, but I find that faking an event with an object is dirty.

It would be great if I could do something like `child['on'+event]()` and let it bubble.

Comment: You can create a real event and then fire it at the child element. IE8, however, does not support this API.

Comment: Can't you just locate child control within parent `e.target` ?

Comment: Btw, if you do fire it from the child (e.g. in the above code if you define 'onclick' on the parent and click on the child - `e.target` will be child

Comment: @YuriyGalanter But sometimes I want to fire `onclick` from javascript, without user interaction.

Comment: @Oriol Seems to work too. When I programmaticaly call child DIV's `click()` method it fires parent DIV's `onclick` event which shows child as `e.target`.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter But that only happens with `onclick` event, which has `click` function. Other events don't have such functions (e.g., `child.mouseover` is `undefined`)

Comment: How then do you programmaticaly raise that event?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I call the handler attached to the event (e.g., `parent.onmouseover()`). The problem is that if `child` has no event handler, I can't call it. And even if I define one, calling it from `child` isn't the same as generating a real event, so it doesn't bubble to `parent`.